# Proving that Measurement increases von Neumann entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, entropy

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the classical sample space of measurement outcomes that may occur in a given experiment, and $M_\mu$, $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$ are a family of measurement operators acting on the pure states of $V$ that satisfy $\sum\limits_{\mu}M_\mu^\dagger M_\mu = Id_V$. The state of the system before the measurement is given by the density operator $\rho$. The probability that the outcome of the experiment is $\mu$ is $P_\rho (\mu) = \operatorname{Tr} ( M_\mu^\dagger M_\mu \rho)$. The system is now in the mixed state
\begin{equation}
\rho' = \sum\limits_{\mu} P_\rho(\mu) \frac{M_\mu \rho M_\mu^\dagger}{P_\rho(\mu)}  =  \sum\limits_{\mu}M_\mu \rho M_\mu^\dagger
\end{equation}

Now I am asked to prove that
$$ S(\rho') \geq S(\rho)$$
where $S$ denotes the *von Neumann* entropy. The hint says, that i should use that 
$$ - {\rm Tr} \left[ \rho \log \tau \right] \geq - {\rm Tr} \left[ \rho \log \rho \right] $$
which I have proven already in a previous exercise.

Unfortunately I do not have any idea how to start. I'm not even sure that the definitions I took from the lecture notes are correct. All I know is that I have to get to
$$ - {\rm Tr} \left[ \sum \limits_{\mu}M_\mu \rho M_\mu^\dagger \log \rho' \right] = - {\rm Tr} \left[ \rho \log \rho' \right]$$
in order to apply the hint. I tried to write it in a basis where either $\rho$ or $\rho'$ are diagonal but I found no way of achieving the above, I'm still feeling uncomfortable with density and measurement operators and appreciate any hint.

PS: I'm not sure whether this is more of a math.SE question, but given the physical meaning of the calculation I decided to post it here. I'm happy to move it if it is considered unsuitable for physics.SE.

Comment: Measurement in physicist's sense results in more information about the system and thus lower information entropy. Von Neumann entropy should reflect this as well, so if you need to prove that von Neumann entropy increases, I am not sure $M_\mu$ should be thought of as representing measurement. Perhaps uncontrolled disturbance would be a better name.

Answer (score 0):

You need use the hint twice. The last equation in your statement should be an inequality. In order to obtain this inequality you need use the hint again.

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment. Once you get to 50 rep you can comment on posts.

Comment: It does seem to represent an attempt to answer the question. I'd consider it an answer.